# Problem with thickness in 3D plots

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I'm facing a problem with Mathematica 11.1.1 on MacOS (2016 Macbook Pro). The `Thickness` and `AbsoluteThickness` options in `PlotStyle` do not scale consistently. There is a "jump" around the value `AbsoluteThickness[3]` (for `Thickness` the value depends on the image size).

```
ParametricPlot3D[{{Cos[t], Sin[t], .2}, {Cos[t], Sin[t], -.2}}, {t, 0, 10}, 
PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
PlotStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[3.00001], AbsoluteThickness[3.]}]
```

The problem is visible in the notebook and also in files exported with the command `Export`, independently of the type (vector PDF, PNG,...) and or resolution (see image below).

This is a regression, because I have notebooks written in version 10 that do not have the problem, but the problem occurs if I reevaluate them with this version. I can't say if the problem was introduced in v11 or in a successive release. The problem is not there on a Ubuntu setup with Mathematica 11.1.1.

Can anyone reproduce this?

[image: File produced with export]

Comment: I have `MMA 11.1.0.0` on Windows 8.1 and is OK. :)

Comment: Use `AbsoluteThickness[]` if you want thickness that is independent of image size. (Pay special attention to the second sentence of `Thickness[]`'s usage message.) Also, please don't use the [tag:bugs] tag until your observations have been confirmed by other users.

Comment: Your code works fine on MMA 10.4 on Win10.

Comment: @J.M. the problem is the same with `AbsoluteThickness` around the value of `3`. Now, as you correctly point out, it is independent of the image size. I edited the question.

Answer (score 6):

It turns out that Dashed does not suffer from this problem. A temporary fix is to use a dashed line with ridiculously large length for the dash:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{{Cos[t],Sin[t],.2},{Cos[t],Sin[t],-.2}},   
 {t,0,10},PlotRange->{{-1,1},{-1,1},{-1,1}},PlotStyle->
 {AbsoluteThickness[3.00001],
 {AbsoluteDashing[{1000,0}],AbsoluteThickness[3.]}}
]
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) Nice find!

Comment: It's nice that we find workarounds for this but I believe that people at Wolfram should address this since it clearly is a bug on the Mac platform

Comment: Wolfram has a link for reporting bugs: http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/, I suggest that you send them a note.

Comment: @Pincopallino I have an idea it's a design choice and not a bug; and if my idea is correct, it makes sense - albeit in hindsight - that dashing appears to be a workaround, since dashing would invoke a general line-drawing algorithm instead of an optimized, undashed, single-pixel-width one. I do think there should be an option to turn the threshold on or off.

Comment: My view is it's a bug. Not only is it undocumented (it cost me days of trial and error), but as @Mariusz said,  the problem does not show up in Windows.

Comment: Did you report it to WRI? Have they responded yet?

Comment: I had though that @Pincopallino would, since he reported it first. I will report  it and report back to the list.

Comment: @Themis I did file a report but haven't heard anything from them yet. I think that you should report it as well. The more reports the better I think

Comment: @MichaelE2: I reported the problem on 1/17/2017 and today I received an acknowledgement that the problem has been forwarded to the developers.

Answer (score 1):

I can, but to a less severe extent. Mathematica 11.0.1, on Mid 2015 Macbook Pro (15" retina display with standard resolution) with macos 10.12.6

[image]

And the new code with `AbsoluteThickness`

```
ParametricPlot3D[{{Cos[t], Sin[t], .2}, {Cos[t], Sin[t], -.2}}, {t, 0,   10}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[3.00001], AbsoluteThickness[3.]}
]
```

produces

[image]

Comment: What mac do you have? What is the resolution of the screen? Also, can you try with the new code in the question, which uses `AbsoluteThickness` instead of `Thicnkess`?

Answer (score 1):

I get the same problem on my Mac:

```
$Version
(*  "11.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 11, 2017)"  *)
```

It's a `Graphics3D` issue. The discontinuity also happens with `Thickness[]`, but the cutoff changes with the width of the image.
I think it's an optimization, and at the cutoff, rendering switches from a fast, pixel-width routine to one that calculates thickness.  But that's just a guess.

There is a setting that gives a more continuous variation in thickness, but at a cost.  See [`RenderingOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RenderingOptions.html):

```
{
 thickness = 2.5; 
 plot = ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[u], Cos[u], u/10}, {u, 0, 20}, 
   PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[thickness], ImageSize -> 300];
 Style[plot, RenderingOptions -> {"3DRenderingEngine" -> "Mesa"}],
 thickness = 3.; 
 plot = ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[u], Cos[u], u/10}, {u, 0, 20}, 
   PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[thickness], ImageSize -> 300];
 Style[plot, RenderingOptions -> {"3DRenderingEngine" -> "Mesa"}]
 }
```

[image]

I see a difference in thickness (you can adjust `thickness` as desired), but it also looks to me that some paint has flaked off.